# Regular Expression - Find all matches after string but before character

Tags: php, regex

I have such a string :

```
CN=whatevername,OU=whatever1,OU=whatever2,DC=domain,DC=com
```

And I'm trying to get which is following "OU" until next comma. So in my example, I would like to receive "whatever1" and "whatever2".

I have tried this but it returns me the rest of the string until last comma.

```
(?<=OU=).*(?=,)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `(?<=OU=).*?(?=,)` or `(?<=OU=)[^,]+` or `OU=\K[^,]+`

Comment: OU=(?<value>\w+) https://regex101.com/r/4NkgNy/1

Comment: Returns me only first occurrence. How can I get all of them please ?